# Multi-language ePub

Tags: arabic, epub

I searched high and low but couldn't find a single ebook in a non-english language, especially Arabic? Does ePus support non-english languages? Does it support Arabic (right to left)?

Thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[This link](http://blog.threepress.org/2009/11/21/bidirectional-text-in-epub/) contains information on using right to left languages in epubs. It also links to Project Gutenberg which contains epubs which support right to left languages.